# Custom domain name setting on Heroku

Tags: heroku, dns, custom-domain

I have set up a custom domain name on an application of mine on Heroku, or at least tried to do so; I followed this page: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains.

The custom domain name is: *myapp.site*

The native Heroku address is: *https://myapp.herokuapp.com/*

But when I now point my web browser to: *https://myapp.site/*

I see this result:

```
Secure Connection Failed

An error occurred during a connection to myapp.site. SSL peer has no certificate for the requested DNS name.

Error code: SSL_ERROR_UNRECOGNIZED_NAME_ALERT

The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.

Learn more…
```

Here are the DNS records I have set for this app:

```
Type    Host                Answer
ANAME   myapp.site      blah-blah-234567.herokudns.com
CNAME   www.myapp.site  blih-bleh-456789.herokudns.com
```

Here is the result of running the *heroku domains* command:

```
me@MyMac myapp % heroku domains
=== myapp Heroku Domain
myapp.herokuapp.com

=== myapp Custom Domains
Domain Name    DNS Record Type DNS Target                       SNI Endpoint 
myapp.site     ALIAS or ANAME  blah-blah-234567.herokudns.com   undefined    
www.myapp.site CNAME           blih-bleh-456789.herokudns.com   undefined    
me@MyMac myapp %
```

It would be useful to have some indications on what I need to do to solve this issue?

Comment: Are you using Eco-tier dynos?

Comment: Yes. I actually discovered yesterday that this was the issue.